# RewriteRule - 4 values error

Tags: .htaccess

My current .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ $1.php [L]   
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ $1.php?one=$2 [L]   
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ $1.php?one=$2&two=$3 [L]

DirectoryIndex Home.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404
```

There's no error here, but as soon as I add the following

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ $1.php?one=$2&two=$3&three=$4 [L]
```

My webpage gives an `Internal Server Error`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of your .htaccess scripts are giving any errors to me or my own website.

I've tested your Regular Expressions on two websites, and give no errors.
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/aN7

https://www.debuggex.com/r/UBHXW6KJTDmRqewc

Whatever may have caused the error, its not your `RewriteRule`.

I suggest you start off with a new, clean .htaccess file, testing every time you add a new line. I suggest you add the `DirectoryIndex` last.

Comment: I've tried doing what you said, but it keeps giving me an `Internal Server Error`. I've even tried removing everything but the `RewriteRule`

Comment: @InzeBielderman If you start with a new .htaccess (so don't empty the current one, start a new file), after what line does the error start occurring?

Comment: As soon as I add `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ $1.php?one=$2&two=$3&three=$4 [L]` to it.

Comment: @InzeBielderman Okay, on what request URL do you see this message appear? After you have three/four `/`, or on any URL?

Comment: It seemd to be a problem with my server, I contacted my server host about this. My server thought the file I uploaded was too big, so it just removed all the ENTERs in the file